# I want to use Vue local, but it doesnt work

Tags: vue.js, local

I have index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module">
        import Vue from '/static/js/vue.js'

        new Vue({
            el: '#index',
            data:{
                message:'Hello Vue!'
            }
        })
    </script>
    <div id="index">
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

also I have this file structure

[image]

But I get this error:

GET http://localhost:8080/static/js/vue.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Can anybody help me? I want to use Vue.js without webpack, npm or something else.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `index.html` is a sibling of the `/js` folder, so shouldn't your path be `import vue from '/js/vue.js';` instead?

Comment: WebPack creates server, that serves these files during development. You are trying to get something from `localhost:8080` who is listening there now?

Comment: I have spring boot rest controller. It works, if  i delete vue import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your Vue scripts at the end of the body and as @Terry suggested change the path of your vue.js script to '/js/vue.js':

here's a working example https://codepen.io/ellisdod/pen/PoqBRbg?editors=1010

```
<body>
    <div id="index">
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>

        new Vue({
            el: '#index',
            data:{
                message:'Hello Vue!'
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```